# Process 2 messages at the same time

Tags: c++, winapi, tcp, message-queue, winsock

I have the following code to be able to receive data over tcp and be able to send
data at the same time over winsock. However, only one of the messages gets processed in the queue, and I would like to be able to both process keystrokes and receive data over the socket asynchronously.

How would I be able to do that without blocking one of the message queues

```
#define WM_SOCKET_MSG (WM_APP + 1)

int main()
{
    Init();
    S = ConnectToServer("192.168.2.10", 54782);

    char _buf[1024] = { 0 };

    /*
    HHOOK WINAPI SetWindowsHookEx(
      _In_ int       idHook,
      _In_ HOOKPROC  lpfn,
      _In_ HINSTANCE hMod,
      _In_ DWORD     dwThreadId
    );
    */
    // Start the hook of the keyboard
    KeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(
        WH_KEYBOARD_LL, // low-level keyboard input events
        HookProcedure, // pointer to the hook procedure
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), // A handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure 
        NULL //desktop apps, if this parameter is zero
    );
    if (!KeyboardHook) {
        // Hook returned NULL and failed
        GetLastError();
    }
    else
    {

        WSAAsyncSelect(S, NULL, WM_SOCKET_MSG, FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CLOSE);

        int n;
        char command[20];
        MSG Msg;
        while (GetMessageW(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
        {
            switch (Msg.message)
            {
                case WM_SOCKET_MSG:
                {
                    int event = WSAGETSELECTEVENT(Msg.lParam);
                    int error = WSAGETSELECTERROR(Msg.lParam);
                    if (error != 0)
                    {

                        break;
                    }

                    switch (event)
                    {
                    case FD_READ:
                        n = recv(S, _buf, sizeof(_buf) - 1, 0);
                        if (n > 0) {
                            // process data as needed ...
                            MessageBoxA(0, _buf, _buf, 0);
                        }
                        else {
                            //error
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

            break;
            }

            // process other messages as needed ... 
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);
        }
    }

    unhookKeyboard();
    // Exit if failure
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to do two types of events asynchronously, you can't process them using only a single event loop - the event loop fundamentally processes one event at a time, before processing the next.  Generally speaking, you will need to move the heavy processing into another thread, and your event loop will need to (quickly) receive data and bundle it up so it may be processed by the other thread.   Bear in mind that access to any data structure accessed by two threads (e.g. your event loop stores received data and worker thread retrieves/clears it) needs to be synchronised (e.g. using a mutex)

Comment: you can use asynchronous I/O on sockets

Comment: [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjects).

Comment: @IInspectable Should i do it before or after ```while (GetMessageW(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)``` ?

Comment: when using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` (better with Ex) you must not call `GetMessageW` at all. you must call `PeekMessageW` if `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` return `nCount`